# Dynamically create HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

I am using parse backend. There is a list on my server which gets incremented  with data when some user submits something. Now, on my website, I want to access that data. But I dont know, at a given point of time, how many rows of data will be present in that list. ( Basically, u can say I am making something like a shopping website where the user gets a list of objects when they open my site, with the exception that this "list" is constantly changing). I want all the items to be displayed. 
How can I achieve this?

Here's what I have tried:
HTML:

```
<table style="width: 600px; text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;">
<tr>

<th><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th><strong>Score</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr>

<td id="tdn0">-</td>
<td id="tds0">-</td>

</tr>


<tr>

<tr>

<td id="tdn1">-</td>
<td id="tds1">-</td>

</tr>
```

To populate this, I use javascript/jquery. I fetch data and use getElementById and change innerHTML (Note the ID's are in numeric order). But the problem is that if I create 20 elements and server returns 25 elements, 5 elements are not shown and if server returns 15 elements, 5 elements are shown with dashes. 
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

EDIT-------
The script looks like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
{
    var object = results[i];
    flag=0;

    if(i===0)
    {
        down[counter]=object.get('UserName');// save username
    down_score[counter]=object.get('score');  // save score in user defined array
    // alert(down[counter]);
    counter++;
    continue;
    }

    else
    {
        for(var j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(object.get('UserName')===down[j]){  //  check for duplication of data
            flag=1;}
        }
        if(flag!==1)
        {
            down[counter]=object.get('UserName');
        down_score[counter]=object.get('score');    
            counter++;
        }
    }
}


for(var k=0; k<21;k++){
    document.getElementById('tdn'+k).innerHTML=down[k];  //  spit out the results in HTML
    document.getElementById('tds'+k).innerHTML=down_score[k];

}
```

Here, results is an array of objects returned by the server.

Comment: where is your script?

Comment: Please see the edit I made. This is the script.

Comment: So the question is how to get the last index from your HTML and append a new element below the last item ?

Comment: @user26409021, yes, exactly what I want. Any ideas?